# XNA How to create separate ContentManager?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

With XNA 4.0, I tried to create multiple content managers for different game screens by something like this:

```
ContentManager myManager = new ContentManager(Content.ServiceProvider, Content.RootDirectory);
```

with Content being the original ContentManager the system provides me with.

However, it didn't work out like I had expected. If I call myManager.Unload() then everything loaded with the original ContentManager are unloaded as well. It was as if the two held the same data.

How can I seperate them out and make unloading of one manager not affect the other?

Comment: Why do you need more than one content manager for your game?

Comment: I think the problem may lie in both content managers using the same instance of `Content` or `Content.ServiceProvider`. Try creating a separate content manager without using them.

Comment: I want when any of the screens becomes inactive, its content is unloaded automatically so as not to use up too much memory. The ContentManager constructor requires those two parameters (ServiceProvider and RootDirectory) and I didn't know where else I could get those so I used those of the original content manager the game had provided me with.

Comment: I think you should just keep track of all unloadable objects that are currently loaded for the active screen and then unload them when switching to a new screen. It's like having lots of magnets on a fridge door and throwing away the whole fridge instead of taking all magnets off its door every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. Personally I use `Game.Services` - but `Content.ServiceProvider` is fine too - they both point at *exactly the same object*.

The bug must be elsewhere in your code. Are you *absolutely* sure you are using the correct content manager in each case?

Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger? And making use of the "Make Object ID" function? (In the context menu for watch variables or variables that you mouse-over.)